# How to get a browser to spot this javascript/jquery syntax error?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I had a subtle typo in a javascript I was testing - a double-apostrophe instead of a single. Can you spot it?

```
$('#visa, #mastercard').click(function() {
    $('#creditCard input').attr('disabled', false).css('backgroundColor",''); 
    $('#creditCard label').css('color','');
});
```

My question is - is there a way to have this error flagged in the browser? When I look at the console in both Chrome and Firefox (firebug), nothing shows up.

Comment: The syntax highlighting really helps in spotting it :)

Comment: Are you writing that code in Notepad? `:P`

Comment: The problem, of course, is 'backgroundColor" with the unmatched single-double quote. I've done this kind of things many times. I second the idea of using syntax highlighting in your editor (I use UltraEdit from IDM), but the thing that has helped me has been to have a strict set of rules for using quotes. For me it always works best to use ' to start with and then " for quoted items internal to the '. I don't know of any way to have the browser flag it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting this error (with information about the file and line number):

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Use the syntax highlighting feature of your IDE to detect such errors.

Comment: A good IDE for Windows is [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). I myself use [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/) (Linux).

Comment: How do I see this error? I look at Console in firebug, but nothing. Same with tools, javascript console, console on Chrome.

Comment: any idea how I can see this in the browser? It's escaping me - haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @JackBeNimble Firefox/Chrome: Ctrl+Shift+J, clear the console and Reload page. The error should show up.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an editor with highlighting, it'll show up immediately since the colors will be reversed every line after that.  It even shows up on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
$('#creditCard input').attr('disabled', false).css('background-color',''); 
$('#anAirlineName').css('background-color",'');
```

Should be

```
$('#creditCard input').attr('disabled', false).css('background-color',''); 
$('#anAirlineName').css('background-color','');
```

after `background-color` it should be single apostrophe not the double one.

Answer (score 0):

For what it may be worth, I stuck the following in my code:

```
$('#anAirlineName).css('backgroundColor",'');
```

and I did get in the Firebug error console 'unterminated string literal' and it gave the filename name and line number.

The way I'm set up, I don't see the Firebug error console, unless I click the rightmost red x on the Firebug menu line.